# Error while executing a sql command in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using asp.net with c# and there exist an error in these line of codes.

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = "c";
    string FID = Session["FID"].ToString();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //int str_diff = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Difference"]);
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    cmd.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
    cmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = type;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

    Response.Redirect("~/Faculty/Personaldet.aspx");
}
```

[image: Error!!!]

Comment: what error you are getting and on which line

Comment: i shown the error in the image attached itself

Comment: have you tried updating directly from sql server?

Comment: Yes @Nisha i have tried updating directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set the connection to the command

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the `SqlConnection` to the `SqlCommand`. As an additional suggestion I would wrap the connection in a using block to ensure it is correctly disposed in the case of an exception.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True") 
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    cmd.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
    cmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = type;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: And if you're wrapping - then you should **also** wrap the `SqlCommand` in a `using() { ... }` block to ensure its proper disposal

Answer (score 0):

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update TrackingFaculty_det SET Type=@Type WHERE (FID=@FID) and DATEDIFF(d,TrackingFaculty_det.LastUpdateDate,GETDATE())>60", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
    cmd.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
    cmd.Parameters["@Type"].Value = type;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes @Nisha i got the answer

Comment: Good. Try figuring solutions by yourself to the maximum before asking for help. It will help you learn more.

Comment: I had to produce the solution so urgently so i asked the help.